Removing GND and Power planes under the feedback pins and traces in opamp layout
I want to use a reference design form Texas instrument as a reference for my layout for OPA838, I noticed this reference design is a 4-layer board (signal-GND-Power-signal):

Reference: the image is a screenshot from the layout of PCB "OPA838DBVEVM"  and the file is only available from TI:
As we can see in the picture, there are  polygon cutout both for GND and power plan, but I noticed, there is no polygon cutout for pin 5,6,2, which are positive and negative supply and enable pin, why we have kept GND and power plan underneath these pins?
My second questions is:
In this layout I can see under the signal trace (Signal Trace in the picture), we have discontinuously of the GND underneath the trace, can this cause any issue from layout standpoint? considering as a general rule for high speed routing we should provide a return path for signal traces, this return path is GND plan underneath the signal, but in this case we do not have it or we have it but in a discontinuous way (for Signal Trace). Please let me know if I'm right or not, if yes, how we can optimize the layout?

(When I came back to double check this answer a little while later before posting, I found this post on TI E2E that appears to be the same question, as is the answer the reply gave to my answer, for the most part.)
Removing the copper planes below the pins primarily serves, particularly with high speed amplifiers, to reduce parasitic capacitance, which can impact the stability, gain characteristics, and bandwidth of the amplifier, as it forms an undesirable parasitic pole. Thus, they choose to remove the planes there to preserve performance. There is no such need for the other pins, since they have no specific sensitivity to capacitance, and will instead benefit from the ground plane.
Secondly, the discontinuity, although unfortunate, isn't as important as low parasitic capacitance, as that trace is also part of the output pin geometry. The nearest ground plane isn't too far, either, so the total return path, although poorly defined, is going to be small.

Also, if you a capacitive source impedance, these parasitic capacitance can attenuate the signal towards the input of your frontend, thus increasing input-referred noise.
